# Update specific fields using EF in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an application that needs to be able to update data. There is a table called "HomePage" with multiple fields. For ease of use, I want the user to update just 2 fields in this table(Description1 and Description2). While trying to achieve this, it does update these 2 fields but the rest of the data in the other fields in the table are deleted. Please check below code

**Controller.cs**

```
 // GET: HomePages/Edit/5
        public ActionResult EditDescription(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            HomePage homePage = db.HomePages.Find(id);
            if (homePage == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(homePage);
        }

        // POST: HomePages/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditDescription([Bind(Include = "ID,Description1,Description2,TestName1,TestName2,TestName3,TestComp1,TestComp2,TestComp3,TestDesc1,TestDesc2,TestDesc3,FooterAddress,FooterEmail,FooterTel,FooterFax")] HomePage homePage)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(homePage).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(homePage);
        }
```

**cshtml**

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

  <hr /> @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description1, 5, 100, null) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description2 , 8, 100, null) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
      <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" style="color:white;background-color:#ad301c" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the @Html.HiddenFor tag helper for the fields that you do not want to edit. This way the view will send the field data back to the POST method in your controller. For example: `<input type="hidden" asp-for="TestName1" />` or `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TestName1)` will pass the TestName1 field to the post method in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding all model and gets only 2 elements.

```
[Bind(Include = "ID,Description1,Description2,TestName1,TestName2,TestName3,TestComp1,TestComp2,TestComp3,TestDesc1,TestDesc2,TestDesc3,FooterAddress,FooterEmail,FooterTel,FooterFax")]
```

So try to do this without Bind option.